# InstallShield 2015 Automation DeleteShortcut and DeleteSubFolder in VBS

Tags: vbscript, automation, installshield

Im using the InstallShield 2015 automation interface in vbs to automate setup generation.

At the beginning my startmenu folder (System Configuration -> Shortcuts) structure looks like this:

```
Shortcuts -> [TaskBarFolder] -> [StartMenuFolder] -> ProgramMenuFolder -> ProgramMenuCompanyFolder -> ProgramMenuProductFolder -> NewShortcut1
```

I would like to change it dynamically with the automation vbs script.

I want to delete "ProgramMenuProductFolder" with the "NewShortcut1" included
and i want to rename the displayname of "ProgramMenuCompanyFolder". After that i want to add a new shortcut to the "ProgramMenuCompanyFolder" folder.

The other possibility might be to move the shortcut one level up to  "ProgramMenuCompanyFolder" rename it and delete "ProgramMenuProductFolder" after that...?

Programatically i can set a Shortcut Displayname like this without problems:

```
pProject.ISWiFeatures.Item("Hauptanwendung").ISWiComponents.Item("CMP_StartMenuShortcut").ISWiFolders.Item("[TaskBarFolder]").SubFolders("[StartMenuFolder]").SubFolders("[ProgramMenuFolder]").SubFolders("ProgramMenuCompanyFolder").SubFolders("ProgramMenuProductFolder").ISWiShortcuts.Item("NewShortcut1").DisplayName = "New name string"
```

I have suspected that i can delete it like that:

```
pProject.ISWiFeatures.Item("Hauptanwendung").ISWiComponents.Item("CMP_StartMenuShortcut").ISWiFolders.Item("[TaskBarFolder]").SubFolders("[StartMenuFolder]").SubFolders("[ProgramMenuFolder]").SubFolders("ProgramMenuCompanyFolder").SubFolders("ProgramMenuProductFolder").DeleteShortcut("NewShortcut1")
```

I also get type missmatch error when i try something like:

```
pProject.ISWiFeatures.Item("Hauptanwendung").ISWiComponents.Item("CMP_StartMenuShortcut").ISWiFolders.Item("[TaskBarFolder]").SubFolders("[StartMenuFolder]").SubFolders("[ProgramMenuFolder]").SubFolders("ProgramMenuCompanyFolder").DeleteSubFolder("Display name of folder")
```

Comment: It may help isolate which step has a type mismatch if you separate these calls into multiple lines. e.g. `set pFeatures = pProject.ISWiFeatures` \\ `set pComponents = pFeatures.Item("Hauptanwendung")` \\ `...`. And you can start at either the right or left side, or do them all at once.

Comment: I can add a new Folder in this structure without any Problems:            `code`Set m_pFeature = pProject.ISWiFeatures("Hauptanwendung")
Set m_pComponent = m_pFeature.ISWiComponents("CMP_StartMenuShortcut")
Set iswi_pFolder = m_pComponent.ISWiFolders("[TaskBarFolder]")
Set m_pFolder = iswi_pFolder.SubFolders("[StartMenuFolder]")
Set m_pFolderUeberPups = m_pFolder.SubFolders("[ProgramMenuFolder]")
Set m_pFolderPups = m_pFolderUeberPups.SubFolders("ProgramMenuCompanyFolder")

m_pFolderUeberPups.AddSubFolder("Test123")